# Align div to top of container

Tags: css-float, vertical-alignment

You can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWg7F/) that the `search` div is centre aligned, how can I make it align to the top?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="banner">
        <a href="#"><h1>Title</h2><br />
        <h2>Subtitle</h2></a>
        <div id="search">
            <label>Search</label>
            <input type="textbox"/>
            <input type="submit" />
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width:85%;
    margin:35px auto;
}

#banner{
    height:150px;
    padding:30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#search{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    width:38%;
}

#banner h1, #banner h2{
margin:0;padding:0;color:#A2A2A2;display:inline;
}
#banner h1{
font-size:50px;
}
#banner h2{
font-size:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options. If you want to float the search `div` to right, move it up in the `html` code. Now the search div floats right to the elements that are *after* it in the code. (Note that you had an unclosed div in the original code.)

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWg7F/10/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="search">
      <label>Search</label>
      <input type="textbox"/>
      <input type="submit" />
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    </div>
    <a class="" href="#"><h1>Title</h2><br />
    <h2 class="">Subtitle</h2></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other option is to make the preceding elements (`a` and `h2`) float to the left side of the search `div` but that doesn't look so good as the search `div` is not at the right edge of the browser window.